# What would the propType be of a JSX prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react you can set the propType of the props that come into a component. For one of my props I want the value to either be null or a line of JSX. The React docs don't cover what propType should be used for JSX.

When testing this I found that it wouldn't throw errors when using the propTypes of object or element. When using another such as symbol I would get an error that said it was an object. If it was an object surely it should complain when it's an element.

What is the correct propType for JSX?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try using this propType...

```
React.PropTypes.element
```

Comment: That works but I'm not sure if it's right. object also works and when I produce warnings it tells me it's an object.

Comment: It is right if you are passing a JSX element. Please see - http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/react.html

Answer (score 5):

`PropTypes.node` or `PropTypes.element` can be used